# Some technically misleading commentary needs removal

Tags: support

On [a C++ answer I posted in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26131954/464581), another SO reader has now added technically nonsense commentary about the current best practice being dangerous. I.e. misleading readers. He persisted after the technical was explained to him (my explanation at red arrow in figure below):

[image]

His last comment makes sense out of context, but is nonsense in context. The odds are very low for that happening by chance. I conclude that it's designed that way; it's a common trolling technique.

I think the proper action in such a case is to call for moderator help. However, flagging his comments as non-constructive only resulted in my comment being deleted, and ditto for flagging with explanation. His commentary needs deletion since it misleads (IMO is designed to mislead) readers.

Comment: It seems the both of you disagree. It is impossible for a moderator to judge if either you or your opponent is at fault. I would say the easiest way out is to leave a comment stating you disagree completely and leave it at readers to make their own judgement. Flagging comments to get rid of feedback you don't like is not the way to go IMHO. I would have stopped at the second time calling it nonsense, but that is probably only me.

Comment: @rene: Simple logic is not a matter of agreement or disagreement. Lacking mod support it's possible for me to simply appeal to authority, there is no lack of such. But while that can convince newbie readers it is a fallacy, and I would rather avoid posting a fallacy.

Comment: I also don't think, this can be solved by a mod, but as both of you seem to be experts in c++, I think a (resolvable) missunderstanding between the two of you is more likely than that one of you doesn't correctly understand the technical ramifications of move. And if such missunderstanding can arise even between experts, then this might indicate that your post could benefit from some additional explanation/clarification (once the missunderstanding is resolved).

Comment: One way or another the comments have now been removed.

Comment: Woah, WTF?! If you disagree, just disagree. Why are you going crying to the authorities demanding that dissenting opinions be stripped from the record? Good grief. And you didn't even bother to write a comment to me informing me about this meta post; I had to be pointed to it by someone else, by chance, hours later. Not cool, Alf.

Comment: You'll also notice that basically a single clarifying comment from MikeMB resolved the whole thing without further drama. Perhaps next time you could simply do that instead of throwing a tantrum. Thank you Mike.

Comment: I will also state here for the record that a mod _did_ remove my comments (leaving only the "that's nonsense", "that's nonsense" responses behind), about which I am of course not happy.

Answer (score 6):

Moderators generally will not remove comments based on claims of technical inaccuracy, just as we don't delete answers people think are wrong. As has been stated before, we cannot possibly be subject matter experts on every topic this site covers. If you are thinking about flagging a constructively worded comment for being technically wrong, you might as well stop before you hit that button.

This was the conversation at the time you had flagged the opposing comments:

[image: comment history for this answer]

Everything seemed perfectly civil there until your "That's nonsense" comment, at which point things went downhill. Your flags on the other person's comments were declined, because we're not taking sides in a technical disagreement.

We did step in when you then left the comment

> @BarryTheHatchet: You're talking nonsense. I've flagged your comments about moving as such (not constructive). Please don't introduce more noise. Thank you.

and deleted that because it wasn't helpful at all. You re-added that comment after we deleted it:

> @BarryTheHatchet: I'm sorry, what you write does not make any sense. It's technobabble. To see that it's just dumb, try to create an example.

and we deleted it again. You added the comment yet again after that, which provoked a longer argument, so we tried to clean up all the comments after that, because things were no longer going in a good direction.

If you have a problem with the technical content of a comment, leave a polite comment that explains the problems with their response. Don't take it personally, and don't start a protracted argument in comments. If someone doesn't agree with you, and you've explained yourself to your best ability, it's time to walk away.

Comment: Thanks for removing the comments. Much as I would love to walk away that's impossible because this user, Darkness flies in orbit or whatever, he keeps changing his nick, keeps trolling me (and others). For years. I didn't notice it was him until now. I'm not surprised.

Comment: Re "which provoked a longer argument, so we tried to clean up all the comments after that, because things were no longer going in a good direction.", that does not square with my screen dumps, I'm sorry. A bit of fantasy history.

Comment: Re "don't start a protracted argument in comments", I have not been involved in argumentation at all, so, that's **false**. I called for mods to deal with the trolling, and when they repeatedly failed to do so, but did the opposite, effectively supporting the troll, I posted it here on meta. Sorry I didn't notice the multiple same-way-pointing untruths in your answer earlier. It is consistent with my earlier experience that SO moderator do not provide a reliable service for the content-producing users. Instead, as with the US police, one risks getting charged with this and that, or shot. :(